# Sometimes the keys F, V and Backspace stop working in macOS High Sierra! How to fix this?

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra

I'm having a very odd problem where the keys <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>⌫</kbd> (backspace) stop working for no apparent reason!

Then the problem seems to fix itself some time later, to reappear afterwards.

What's causing this and how to avoid it? It's getting really annoying. And I don't understand why only those 3 keys fail to work, the rest of the keyboard works just fine.

I don't think it's really a hardware issue. I'm on High Sierra 10.13.2. I use Karabiner-Elements to program some keys and at first I thought it could be the culprit (even though I have used it for a long time with no issues), but the problem persists even after quitting that app.

Comment: To determine if it's hardware or software, boot into Safe or Recovery mode.  If the problem persists, it's hardware.

Comment: Do you have another external keyboard that you can use to test if the issue occurs on that one too?

Comment: What model Mac is this?

Comment: I'm using a Mac Mini (mid-2011) with a standard silver Apple Keyboard. And I have another keyboard, but it's a mechanical keyboard that doesn't work with Mac (Ozone Strike Pro). Yes, there are Windows-only keyboards! I didn't know that when I bought it. If I connect the failing Apple Keyboard to a PC, it works correctly, so it's probably not a hardware issue. Plus the Backspace key is too far from the other 2 failing keys (F and V) to be some physical problem with a failing zone of the keyboard.

Comment: Well, after further testing, I have to say it was indeed a hardware issue. Since the problem is intermittent, in previous tests in a PC the keyboard happened to work fine, but in the latest test I've performed in a PC the same F, V and Backspace keys also fail to work in a PC. So it's a hardware problem with the keyboard. So much with Apple's supposed "quality" hardware. I didn't mistreat the keyboard in any way. It just stopped working properly for no reason. Plus I've seen several Apple keyboards like this in eBay with random failing keys. This doesn't happen with PC keyboards, even cheapos!

Comment: If it's a hardware issue, voluntarily close it as a dupe so folks can find the answer!